# Error NaN en angular al sumar montos

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Tengo una función en `angular` la cual me `suma` el monto que le pasa con el parámetro, pero me arroja al final de la `suma` el error `Nan`, que puede ser?, este total lo plasmo en el `html`, espero de su ayuda, gracias!

En otra función, invoco el `sum_total`, ya que en mi `html` tengo una lista con `ckeck box`, entonces la función siguiente selecciona todos los registros, y por ende tengo que  `sumar` todos los montos de cada uno de los registros, el problema es que imprimo cada suma y la hace perfecto, el problema es al ultimo arroja el `NaN`

Seleccionar todo

**aquí invocamos la función `sum_total`**

```
$scope.seleccionar_todo = function () {
        $scope.cuentas.forEach(function (cuenta) {
            cuenta.pagar = $scope.seleccionado;
            $scope.sum_monto(parseFloat(cuenta.importe_total));
        });
    };
```

**función que suma todos los montos**

```
$scope.monto_total=0;

    $scope.sum_monto = function (importe){
        $scope.monto_total= parseInt($scope.monto_total) + parseInt(importe);
        console.log(parseInt($scope.monto_total));
    };
```

html

```
<h4 style="margin-left:990px; ">Monto Seleccionado: {{ monto_total }}</h4>
```

Comment: donde estas llamando la función $scope.sum_monto(param) en el html? puedes agregar mas contenido para identificar el problema y poder dar una solución concreta.

Comment: Que valor le estas mando a la funcion $scope.sum_monto como parametro?

Answer (score 0):

El error era que manda un valor null, lo que no tiendo por que, le paso un valor undefined a la funcion, la respuesta es asi

```
$scope.monto_total=0;

    $scope.sum_monto = function (importe){
        if(importe!==undefined){
            $scope.monto_total = parseFloat($scope.monto_total) + parseFloat(importe);
            console.log(importe + " - " + parseFloat($scope.monto_total));
        }
    };
```

Comment: por eso quería saber que valor le enviabas como parametro